# suction lines freeze for A/C and refrigeration system

Tags: hvac

Why do suction lines freeze when there is low refrigerant in air conditioning system but on the contrary for refrigeration system freeze when there is too much refrigerant.

Answer (score 2):

Actually both cases can cause freeze ups the condenser is expecting a limited range of gas back (temp and pressure).

when the gas pressure is low it expands more causing excessive cooling thus freezing.

The over fill side there is two much liquid in the system that never released it’s heat in the evaporator so the heat is still being released.

For the cooling system to properly work the system is charged to specific values using pressure and temp gauges we can see the health of the system.

I may have over simplified the answer but getting into super heat and sub cooling is beyond most but that is the temp and pressure we measure and set this in a fairly narrow range for optimal performance.